# Error: File to import not found or unreadable: breakpoint

Tags: sass, breakpoints

I can't seem to get Breakpoint to load successfully.

- I have added @import "breakpoint";
- I have added require 'breakpoint'

The error log in terminal shows:

```
Running "compass:dev" (compass) task
    error _/components/sass/styles.scss (Line 4: File to import not found or unreadable: breakpoint.
Load paths:
  Compass::SpriteImporter
  /Users/i835059/Desktop/sassycompass/_/components/sass
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/susy-2.1.3/sass)
Compilation failed in 1 files.
```

The error log posted in my css file is as follows:

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: breakpoint.
   Load paths:
     Compass::SpriteImporter
     /Users/i835059/Desktop/sassycompass/_/components/sass
     /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets
     /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/susy-2.1.3/sass
    on line 4 of /Users/i835059/Desktop/sassycompass/_/components/sass/styles.scss

1: @import "compass";
2: @import "compass/reset";
3: @import "susy";
4: @import "breakpoint";
5: 
6: @import "variables";
7: @import "mixins";
8: @import "base";
9: @import "layout";

Backtrace:
/Users/i835059/Desktop/sassycompass/_/components/sass/styles.scss:4
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:66:in `rescue in     import'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:45:in `import'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in  `imported_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:294:in `visit_import'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:152:in `block in visit'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:152:in  `visit'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:161:in `block in visit_children'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:173:in `with_environment'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit_children'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:180:in `visit_root'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:151:in `visit'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/engine.rb:268:in `render'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:486:in `update_stylesheet'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:214:in `block in update_stylesheets'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:208:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:208:in `update_stylesheets'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/sass_compiler.rb:40:in `compile!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/commands/update_project.rb:49:in `perform'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/commands/base.rb:18:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:19:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:43:in `perform!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/bin/compass:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/bin/compass:44:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/bin/compass:44:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/compass:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get around this issue by running:

```
bundle clean --force


bundle install
```

Not sure where the gems were broken and it says be careful running bundle clean, but worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem so I just created an **omega 4 sub-theme**

I thought that there was some bad update for some gems, so I copied all the **gemfiles** in the **omega theme** into my sub-theme.

Run from within the sub-theme :

```
bundle install
```

then:

```
bundle exec guard
```

And everything is alright now

Answer (score 0):

You should check do you really have "breakpoint" gem on your computer. 
Type this in your termial and try to find "breakpoint":

```
gem list --local
```

If there is no this gem, you should install:

```
gem install breakpoint
```

There is another way to use breakpoint in your project, in documentation you can find this:

```
#it no longer has any Ruby requirements and can be run as a Sass package
```

So you can download source of breakpoint via Bower or directly from Github and @import in your stylesheet as simple *.scss file